# split row into two columns with sas proc transpose

Tags: sas, transpose

I have a data set that looks like:

```
unit   A1  B1  A2 B2  A3  B3  ....
  .
  .
  .
```

I need to convert it to:

```
unit   A   B
  1
  2
  3
```

I can transpose each separately with:

```
proc transpose data=test OUT=TESTOUT;
   var A1-A5 B1-B5;
   BY UNIT;
```

but this gives me 1 long column instead of 2

Answer (score 0):

```
proc transpose data=test out=test1(rename=(col1=dat));
by id;
var dat1-dat5;
run;

proc transpose data=test out=test2(rename=(col1=rec));
by id;
var rec1-rec5;
run;

data test3 (drop=_name_);
merge test1 test2;
by id;
run;
```